# UNIX get info about file in all directories matching a pattern

Tags: unix

I have a bunch of directories that all contain a file `/SubDir1/SubDir2/File`, and I want to see the memory of each file under directories matching a certain pattern. How do I do this?

So far I have `ls -l | grep "pattern*` to get a list of the directories, but am stuck at this.

Answer (score 2):

By "memory of each file" I guess you mean file size.

The `find` command will do a better job:

```
find . -name "pattern*" -exec du -b {} \;
```

This will print the file size of every file named `File` in your arborescence along with the file path.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `find` command:

```
find . -name 'pattern*' -printf '%s\t%p\n'
```

Comment: Maybe add `-type f` ?

Answer (score 0):

Bash Pitfall #1: [Don't parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)

You can use `find` or shell patterns:

```
for i in pattern*; do
    cat "$i"
done
```

One of your special problems is to get a list of all files under a set of matching directories, and you can do that with a more elaborate pattern:

```
for i in pattern*/*; do
    if [ -f "$i" ]; then
         cat "$i"
    fi
 done
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what SirDarius said, you can also use the `-R` option to `ls` to get a recursive listing.

Something like `ls -lRh | grep "pattern"` should do what you want.

Comment: I'm not suggesting to parse the output of ls... just to filter it for human consumption. The line above works even if file names contain spaces, and I think it's the simplest solution proposed so far that does what the OP wants.

Comment: Recursive listing from `ls` is not a single-line format. You'd be better of with `ls -lRh "$pattern"` or maybe add `-d` if that's closer to the intention.